BSOD help! - ostensibly caused by classpnp.sys
I have been stuck with a BSOD over the past 5 hours.
I have tried the following to no avail:

Running SFC (system file checker)
Running CHKDSK / r
Updating BIOS with Q-Flash
And finally, resetting my PC.

Additional info:
I installed a new SSD last week for storing games but NOT as boot drive.
I started using a new mouse just right before the BSOD started. I suspected this was the issue at first but after unplugging it and uninstalling my drivers, the problem still persists.
Here are my minidump files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jrK2CED7uDqj4KkqAuSh0-SJj5z_cH8y/view?usp=sharing
Currently writing this post on my PC in safe mode.

What do you mean by, "resetting my PC?" Reinstalling Win 10 from ISO? Also, don't expect someone to download your dump file of 10 MB and go through it. Put  in the question only what is relevant from that file. Seealso https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/classpnp-sys-bsod-error.html

@DrMoishePippik Hi, I used Reset This PC in settings and used the local option. I'm not sure if that means if it was installed from ISO. Do forgive my ignorance.
I ran my dump file through WhoCrashed, it says the error occured in: classpnp.sys and the bugcheck name is SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION but I could already see that from the blue screen.
I had already gone through the steps detailed in the article you sent.
I don't have any experience reading minidump files and am having difficulty wrapping my head around it.
I was hoping someone would point me in the right direction.

I am trying to pinpoint the problem but I'm out of my depth.
Sorry if my question above is too vague. I just don't know enough to ask the right questions.

Try downloading the latest Windows 10 ISO form Microsoft, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10, "Using the tool to create installation media..." Follow directions to reinstall Windows 10, being careful to keep existing files.

Run WinDbg to analyze the memory dump and post the relevant results

I think I managed to fix the issue. Ran WinDbg and saw that the file causing the problems was actually Wdfilter.sys. I replaced the file with a good copy from another PC.

Just wondering why Whocrashed reports a different file causing the problems. Doesn't seem to be a reliable tool.
